# Band Structure for free electrons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

Consider a BCC lattice.

How can I explicitly calculate the expression of the n$^{th}$-energy band $E_n(k)$ with $n=1,2,3,4$ for free electrons from
$\Gamma$ to $N=\frac{2\pi}{a}(1/2, 1/2, 0)$ as a function of the modulus of k?

I suppose that for instance the $E_1(k)=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(k+K)^2$, where $K$ is a lattice vector. But then, how can I express the energy on the direction required? And how can I calculate $E_2(k), E_3(k), E_4(k)$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Think about it. Which lattice vector is $K$?

Comment: Maybe $K$ is the direction vector, so $\frac{2\pi}{a}(1/2,1/2,0)$, makes sense?

Comment: How many inverse lattice vectors are there?

Comment: I'm not sure to be really understanding the question, but I would say 1

Comment: Futhermore, I took a look to this http://what-when-how.com/electronic-properties-of-materials/energy-bands-in-crystals-fundamentals-of-electron-theory-part-2/ in which something like this problem is discussed, but the confusion increases only

Comment: You should read up on reciprocal lattice vectors. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice

Comment: And Brillouin zones https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone